# Central Authentication Service Single Sign On

Tags: liferay, single-sign-on, alfresco, cas

I have implemented CAS version 3.3.2 for both Alfresco community version 4.0.e and Liferay Portal version 6.1.1.
When i try to login on Liferay Service, CAS login shows up, logs in successfully and redirects to Liferay user home, same happens for the ALfresco service.
But this is not desired once we have logged in once to a registered service, upon hitting next service it should not ask for login again at CAS and its not happening in this case.
Also different tickets are issued for each application upon reaching CAS, which appears the cause of problem to me.
Can some one please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance
Kunal Soni

Comment: Using openldap as the user repository for authentication for the three of these....

Comment: The problem was while configuring Liferay and Alfresco woth CAS need to configure the HTTPS protocol over the secured port. And need to add the cert from CAS into truststores of both JVMs, Alfresco and Liferay....

Thanks StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was while configuring Liferay and Alfresco woth CAS need to configure the HTTPS protocol over the secured port and need to add the cert from CAS into truststores of both JVMs, Alfresco and Liferay.

Answer (score 0):

You must add a [client CAS](http://downloads.jasig.org/cas-clients/) in Alfresco's lib, also, there are same filter which be added in web.xml for Alfresco and you must create an electronic certificate and configure it.